CollectionView compositional layout
I've been working in a collectionView that shows the cells in this layout.

|-------Featured--------|


|--Normal--| |--Normal--|


|--Normal--| |--Normal--|

But without success.
private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in
        
        let featuredItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(250))
        let featuredItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: featuredItemSize)

        let normalItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: .absolute(150))
        let normalItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: normalItemSize)

        let pairGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(150))
        let pairGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: pairGroupSize, subitems: [normalItem, normalItem])
        
        let section: NSCollectionLayoutSection
        if sectionIndex == 0 {

            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(250))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [featuredItem])
            section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
        } else {

            section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: pairGroup)
        }

        section.interGroupSpacing = 10
        section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
        
        return section
    }
    
    return layout
}

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel?.products.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.item == 0 {
            guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: FeaturedProductCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? FeaturedProductCell else {
                return UICollectionViewCell()
            }
            if let product = viewModel?.products.first {
                cell.configure(product: product)
            }
            return cell
        } else {
            guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ProductCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ProductCell else {
                return UICollectionViewCell()
            }

            let adjustedIndex = indexPath.item - 1
            if let product = viewModel?.products[adjustedIndex] {
                cell.configure(product: product)
            }
            return cell
        }
    }
}

In this moment, all the cells are "featured" sized. In some of others tries, I manage to display all in normal size, or Feature, normal, normal pattern. The idea is just to haver one feature cell.
Thx in advance

So this is not actually a "custom layout". You are just trying to accomplish this with the built-in compositional layout. ("Custom layout" would mean you are writing your own layout from scratch, on a par with flow layout and compositional layout.) I have edited your title to fix this.

The problem is that you have set up things in the expectation of an initial section with just one cell per row and then another section with two cells per row:
if sectionIndex == 0 {
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(250))
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [featuredItem])
    section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
} else {
    section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: pairGroup)
}

but you are returning 1 from numberOfSections, so there is in fact only one section, the first one:
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

Thus, the else clause above can never be reached; there will always be only section 0.
So you need to return 2 instead. Other adjustments will follow naturally from there.

Here's a demo. This is the entire code of the view controller class:
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { (sectionIndex, layoutEnvironment) -> NSCollectionLayoutSection? in

            let featuredItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(250))
            let featuredItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: featuredItemSize)

            let normalItemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.5), heightDimension: .absolute(150))
            let normalItem = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: normalItemSize)

            let pairGroupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(150))
            let pairGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: pairGroupSize, subitems: [normalItem, normalItem])
            pairGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(10)

            let section: NSCollectionLayoutSection
            if sectionIndex == 0 {

                let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .absolute(250))
                let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [featuredItem])
                section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
            } else {
                section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: pairGroup)
            }

            section.interGroupSpacing = 10
            section.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)

            return section
        }

        return layout
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        2
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0: return 1
        case 1: return 10
        default: fatalError("get real")
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .blue
        return cell
    }
}

And this is what I get:

That's close enough to what you're after. As I said, you can take it from ther to tweak as desired.

With only that, sadly do not change the layout. Still displaying all the cells in featured size. Thx for the idea

I'm sorry but you're wrong about that. If you do what I said, and make the other necessary changes, things will start to fall into place. I do not have time right now to rewrite all of your code for you; I have simply pointed to the obvious stumbling block.

Okay, I wrote the whole thing out for you. I added just one line to your layout generation code, pairGroup.interItemSpacing = .fixed(10), to make it clearer when we have two cells and not one.

Friend, I didn't say that I don't believe you. I'm just saying that with that one change alone, it didn't work. In fact, it took me a bit to arrive at the solution even with the code you provided. Clearly, I'm not at your level, but I did thank you for the idea. Maybe because I'm not a native English speaker, it wasn't understood, or it might have sounded like sarcasm. Thanks again; with your help, I did it.

That is a very reasonable critique of the way I expressed myself and I have removed that phrase from my answer.
